# Native method URL.createObjectURL not working in Angular 1.5

Tags: angularjs, eval

I'm running Angular 1.5.7.

Simple example on [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j46bkg7x/) works, but in real application I get an error:

> angular.js:13708 TypeError:
>
> Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on
>   'URL': No function was found that matched the signature provided.
>
> ```
> at TypeError (native)
>
> at downloadCsv (http://localhost/js/dashboard.js:286:35)
>
> at fn (eval at compile (http://localhost/node_modules/angular/angular.js:14605:15), anonymous:4:267)
>
> at expensiveCheckFn (http://localhost/node_modules/angular/angular.js:15694:18)
>
> at callback (http://localhost/node_modules/angular/angular.js:25622:17)
>
> at Scope.$eval (http://localhost/node_modules/angular/angular.js:17444:28)
>
> at Scope.$apply (http://localhost/node_modules/angular/angular.js:17544:25)
> ```

As you can see, the error happens inside eval.

What I do in real application is calling this function on ng-click:

```
    this.downloadCsv = function () {
        //...
        console.log(URL.createObjectURL);
        var url = URL.createObjectURL(chart.csvBlob);
    };
```

An interesting thing is that this code produces valid console.log

> function () { [native code] }

But it fails to run the method.

Answer (score 1):

Strange, but this happened because `chart.cvsBlob` was undefined. I was confused by what error messages told me.